# Adding installed apps to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I'm building a launcher and trying to figure out how to add a section of the 8 most frequently used apps.

I've tried finding launcher tutorials online but haven't found any that cover the above.

Comment: You may want to split this into three separate questions. Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just about getting you an answer, but also about providing a reliable answer to a single, clear question. Additionally please provide some examples of the existing code you have tried and explain where you are getting stuck. It is a lot easier to help if we know what you have already tried and where you are running into issues. If you have any questions, check out the [help article on asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RedBassett Sorry, I fixed it and made seperate questions... I have no code as I am trying to figure it out and can't find any help to get my answer. Thanks